# iPad App missing icon

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I created an imageview programmatically and filled a png file in it. When I run app in simulator or debug it on the Ipad, everything is fine. I archived app and distributed as a Ad-Hoc deployment ipa. I install ipa file to a iPad, the imageview is disappeared. Who can help me for it? the png file is no problem because use it as background picture no problem.

The source code like below

```
UIImageView *uiImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
uiImageView.image = image;
```

also did this way

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];    
UIImageView * uiImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
uiImageView.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
CGRect frameimage = uiImageView.frame;
frameimage.origin.x = ..;
frameimage.origin.y = ..;
uiImageView.frame = frameimage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Carefully check the case of your image filename. Often you'll find that the simulator is not case sensitive with respect to file names (depending on how your Mac OS X disk is formatted), whereas the simulator *is* case sensitive.

So, for example, if you have an image named `Cat.png` and you try and load it using the resource name `cat.png`, it may work in the simulator, but not on an actual device.

This may not be your exact problem, but is worth checking.

Comment: thank you. I check the filename. I also tried change the filename. It still not work.

Comment: try checking if the file is included for different targets.

Comment: it is solved. I defined two imageview in parent class, but set to a weak type. i changed it to strong, everything is fine. Thanks guys